# Load Testing SQL Alchemy: "TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 3 overflow 0 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30"

Tags: amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, mariadb, amazon-rds

I have a SQL-Alchemy based web-application that is running in AWS.

The webapp has several `c3.2xlarge` EC2 instances (8 CPUs each) behind an ELB which take web requests and then query/write to the shared database.

The Database I'm using is and RDS instance of type: `db.m4.4xlarge`. 
It is running MariaDB 10.0.17

My SQL Alchemy settings are as follows:

```
SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE = 3
SQLALCHEMY_MAX_OVERFLOW = 0
```

Under heavy load, my application starts throwing the following errors:

```
TimeoutError: QueuePool limit of size 3 overflow 0 reached, connection timed out, timeout 30
```

When I increase the SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE from 3 to 20, the error goes away for the same load-test. Here are my questions:

1. How many total simultaneous connections can my DB handle?
2. Is it fair to assume that `Number of Number of EC2 instances * Number of Cores Per instance * SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE` can go up to but cannot exceed the answer to Question #1?
3. Do I need to know any other constraints regarding DB connection pool
   sizes for a distributed web-app like mine?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL can handle virtually any number of "simultaneous" connections.  But if more than a few dozen are *actively* running queries, there *may* be trouble.

Without knowing what your queries are doing, one cannot say whether 3 is a limit or 300.

I recommend you turn on the slowlog to gather information on which queries are the hogs.  A well-tuned web app can easily survive 99% of the time on 3 connections.

The other 1% -- well, there can be spikes.  Because of this, 3 is unreasonably low.